# What can be an expression for $n \mod (a+b)$?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

We know $(a+b) \mod n = ((a \mod n) + (b \mod n)) \mod n$. Similarly, can we break down $n \mod (a+b)$?

Comment: you can not "break down"

Comment: Is there a theorem or so proving the impossibility?

Comment: no,  but many counterexamples try 7=3+4, many rules for 3 and 4 no good one for 7why should there be a theorem for everything wich is not working?

Comment: You can't really prove it's impossible because it's a very vague question. There certainly isn't the same motivation to break down $n \bmod (a + b)$ though. The whole point of breaking down $a + b \bmod n$ is that it's useful if $a$ and $b$ are very large numbers, both of which we can easily reduce modulo $n$. However, if $a$ and $b$ are both "large" compared to $n$ in your case, then $n \bmod a + b$ is just $n$.